# setting a range in vbs not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have two range statements:

```
Set s1 = Sheets("Key").Range("A7:A28")
Set s1 = Sheets("Key").Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(28, 1)
```

The first statement works whether the sheet "Key" is active or not.
The second statement only works when "Key" is active

The second statement results in a run-time error '1004':
Application defined or object defined error

What is the correct way of setting a range using row/column syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your worksheet, and then use that with your range `Cells()` objects:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Key")

With ws
    Set s1 = .Range("A7:A28")
    Set s1 = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(28, 1))
end with
```

Or if you prefer not to declare your worksheet, this would work too:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Key")
    Set s1 = .Range("A7:A28")
    Set s1 = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(28, 1))
end with
```

Notice that I changed your `Cells()` (which is referring to the **ActiveSheet**), to `.Cells()` (which is now referring to your **With Statement**).

Comment: I was about to answer my own question, when you beat me to it.
Without a doubt your's is the fastest response to my questions ever!
Thanks!!

Comment: [:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49268192/5781745)D